# Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS with a corrupted object?

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access, memory-corruption

For some strange reason, I'm encountering an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, specifically in unwrapping and referencing a field. (Reproducible on the Xcode 7 GM.)

Here's the relevant code:

```
// FIXME: BUGGY
let conv_id = client_conversation.conversation_id //!.id
print("ABOUT TO DIE: \(conv_id?.id)")
if conv_id!.id as? String != nil {
    conv_id!.id = "hi"
}
```

It crashes at the `print()` statement. Not sure what I can adequately do to fix this. I've tried the `malloc()` debugging, Zombie objects, and hand-debugging via backtrace.

I've added the definition of these objects:

```
class Message : NSObject {
    required override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

class CONVERSATION_ID : Message {
    var id: NSString = ""
}

class CLIENT_CONVERSATION : Message {
    var conversation_id: CONVERSATION_ID?
    var type = ConversationType()
    var name: NSString?
    var self_conversation_state = CLIENT_CONVERSATION_INTERNAL_STATE()
    var read_state = [CLIENT_CONVERSATION_READ_STATE]()
    var current_participant = [USER_ID]()
    var participant_data = [CLIENT_CONVERSATION_PARTICIPANT_DATA]()
}
```

Another example issue: while `print(conv_id!)` prints

```
(
    "sample string"
)
```

I can't seem to be able to access the string directly.

Comment: The most likely cause would be that `id` is an implicitly-unwrapped optional that's nil, but it's hard to tell with no context (like how any of these things are defined).

Comment: What is the type of client_conversation? Is it possible that conversation_id has been released and you are trying to use an instance that no longer exists?

Comment: Added the definitions.

Comment: You still have not given enough info to allow someone else to reproduce the issue. For example, how is the variable `client_conversation` declared and defined?

Comment: You can find more information from this file: https://github.com/psobot/hangover/blob/master/Hangover/PBLite.swift

Comment: To be more precise, PBLite.swift is doing internal reflection, and Schema.swift has the ProtoJSON definitions. The ConversationList.swift `init()` method calls `add_conversation()` on all the entities, and the issue I'm observing occurs in this method.

Comment: No one is going to go hunting around on github. Well, I'm not anyway. It is your job to provide _here_ a reproducible version of the problem. You have not done so.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you say `!` you are inviting a crash. Rewrite your code so that `!` never appears. Know your Optionals and unwrap every single one of them safely. Learn about how to compare an Optional with nil before unwrapping, or how to use the `if let` construct.

Also, note that this line is sheer nonsense (what I call a "false cast"):

```
if conv_id!.id as? String != nil {
```

An NSString is *always* a String; I am surprised that the compiler is not warning you about this. Thus, the test is meaningless.

Your code should therefore read like this:

```
let conv_id = client_conversation.conversation_id
conv_id?.id = "hi"
```

Notice that there are no false casts and exclamation marks.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the feedback, but the problem is, while `conv_id!` runs just fine, `conv_id!.id` causes the crash. Malloc guards don't show any memory corruption, so I'm a little confused as to how this can be possible.

Comment: Let me ask you this: what if you stop using NSString everywhere? You're using it wrong anyway, you know. Just make id a String.

Comment: I've tried: same exact problem. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` regardless. I've updated the post to explain the issue a little bit better.

Comment: Revised my answer to add some code, showing how to remove your nonsensical `as? String` false cast.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, but I want to be able to *read* without crashing; writing seems to work fine.

Comment: Then you have asked your question badly. I took the code you gave and fixed it. If that is not the code that is giving you trouble, you should have shown the code that _is_ giving you trouble.